# Use position fixed to scroll menu on the left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, responsive

The problem is I have to make div with aside class scrollable, but the right side with picture not.
For now it is not scrollable because position is not fixed (screenshot):

[image]

but if I add `position:fixed;` to aside class - it will be scrollable, but the right side will move left, which is bad.

[image]

```css
body {
     background-color: #2e7744;
     overflow:hidden;
}

.aside {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position:fixed;
 }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="aside col-lg-3">
        <nav class="menu background sidebar card mb-4">
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
                 <li class="nav-item">
                     <span class="nav-link" style="background-color: #71a4ff66">
                          <b class="header">Cat 1</b>
                     </span>
                        <ul class="background">
                            <li class="nav-item hover">
                                <a class="poster-link " href="/poster/index.php?pid=3">
                                     <div>Pic 1</div>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                        <span class="nav-link">
                            <b class="header">Cat 2</b>
                        </span>
                        <ul class="background">
                             <li class="nav-item hover">
                                 <a class="poster-link " href="/poster/index.php?pid=1">
                                    <div>Text 1</div>
                                 </a>
                             </li>
                        </ul>
                   </li>
             </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-4 mt-4">
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                  Picture with text  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Is there an option to solve this problem quick?
This HTML structure works perfectly on mobile, I have to preserver it somehow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is encapsulate the menu pane in a div and then assign position fixed in menu pane class with respect to its parent div.

#### Below is the code to prove the same:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'arial';
}

.container-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
}

.left_pane {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu_pane {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 30%;
}

.menu_pane a {
  padding: 25px 20px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.menu_pane a:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}

.right_pane {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
}

.content_pane {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content_pane h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.content_pane p {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="left_pane">
    <div class="menu_pane">
      <a href="#/">Button 1</a>
      <a href="#/">Button 2</a>
      <a href="#/">Button 3</a>
      <a href="#/">Button 4</a>
      <a href="#/">Button 5</a>
      <a href="#/">Button 6</a>
      <a href="#/">Button 7</a>
      <a href="#/">Button 8</a>
      <a href="#/">Button 9</a>
      <a href="#/">Button 10</a>
      <a href="#/">Button 11</a>
      <a href="#/">Button 12</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right_pane">
    <div class="content_pane">

      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content_pane">

      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content_pane">

      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content_pane">

      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content_pane">

      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content_pane">

      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```